# interact with RFID and facebook

Tags: c++, python, facebook, mechanize, rfid

So, i want to retrieve an ID from one RFID card

this is where it gets tricky for me. I have the option of creating a facebook app, but as far as i can tell, facebook only let's you log if you enter your credentials, if you have cookies stored then an access token is requested.

I want people to put a card close to my rfid reader and that makes a like on something.

**problem one:** there is no cookies stored and people only use a card (no GUI anywhere), i could associate one account to an rfid UID and ask the user to give account details and then securely store them. I think it's agains't the facebook TOS...

**problem two:** depending on how the information is submitted to facebook it will change the language used here, tell me your opinion; if i can store the data, i could use Python Mechanize to submit the info to an API;

**problem three:** don't know much about rfid readers, need to read a bit more here, but seems there are some arduinos and chips doing the reading. What should be used here? C++, java or Python to get to the problem two?

What is your suggestion on dealing with this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: _“I want people to put a card close to my rfid reader and that makes a like on something.”_ – I would not consider this to be in line with Facebook’s policies _at all_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Question 3:

I assume that you meant 13MHz RFID (which is used in all modern systems, like passports, handys=NFC, ...)

The standard Softwareinterface for RFID-readers is PC/SC ( http://www.pcscworkgroup.com ). It is OS independent, provides bindings for any language and every manufacturer provides pcsc-drivers for his readers.

The Pythonbindings for PCSC are http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyCSC/0.3

Comment: Thanks for the info. What about the rest of the problems, how would you handle them?